# Mongo DB : db.stats() show 1 collection, but not listed in getCollectionNames() -- not a version issue

Tags: mongodb

In mongo shell. I get below output with db.stats(). But db.getCollectionNames() returns an empty set. How do I find this last collection? Or drop it somehow. Another DB where I dropped all the collections, the DB went away; but not this one. So, this is not a version mismatch issue as in another post. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
MongoDB Enterprise myReplicaSet:PRIMARY> db.stats()
{
        "db" : "My_MONGODB",
        "collections" : 1,
        "views" : 0,
        "objects" : 0,
        "avgObjSize" : 0,
        "dataSize" : 0,
        "storageSize" : 20480,
        "numExtents" : 0,
        "indexes" : 1,
        "indexSize" : 20480,
        "fsUsedSize" : 4900917248,
        "fsTotalSize" : 34342961152,
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1591713311, 1),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1591713311, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"BoA+RSuChh8z2nW/xm6m2TyVrr0="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("6781638122116481027")
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/ only shows collections you have privileges on, use a user account with global admin permissions.

Comment: @D. SM - thank you